# I don't think that he would take such a decision

Tags: tense, will-would

> I don't think that he **would** take such a decision.
>
> I don't think that he **will** take such a decision.

Is there any difference between them?

The only difference is 'would' vs. 'will'.

Comment: Do you know the difference between "would" and "will" generally?

Comment: I don't think I do. The reason is that 'would' has a variety of usages.

Comment: This would contains an implied if clause at the end. I don't think that he would take such a decision [if he was thinking about it.] For example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed a difference—they mean different things. The *would* sentence is in the conditional mood. Implicit in it is “under circumstances *C*.” The *will* sentence is the ([realis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realis_mood)) future tense. It is making a prediction (or promise) of what will definitely happen, come what may.

Consider this parallel pair:

> I don’t think he’s awake yet. **If he were**, I **would** hear him puttering around upstairs

and

> He’s still asleep. **When he awakens**, I **will** let him know you visited.

Or this pair:

> If Hillary Rodham Clinton had been elected, the Supreme Court **would not have taken** such a lurch toward the political right

and

> Now that Joe Biden has been elected, the Supreme Court **will not take** a further lurch rightward in the next four years.

The Clinton sentence is an irrealis, it discusses a condition that is contrary to the actual facts—she was **not** elected. The Biden sentence is realis. After all, he was indeed elected, so the main clause is a prediction free of any limiting conditions.

So, returning to your own pair, the *would* version is appropriate in contexts like “He is simply not the sort of person likely to take such a decision, even under great inducements.” And the *will* version is suited to contexts like “Her behavior has left him no choice; his taking such a decision has become, I believe, a certainty.”

Comment: What's the nuance?

Comment: See my modified version, which elaborates on the nuance.

Comment: The nuance is an implied if clause.